# I am getting an exception raised and I can't figure out why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def permutations(string, step = 0):
    # convert parameter to string in case we received something else
    try:
        if isinstance(string, str):
            # if we've gotten to the end, print the permutation
            if step == len(string):
                print "".join(string)

            # everything to the right of step has not been swapped yet
            for i in range(step, len(string)):

                # copy the string (store as array)
                string_copy = [character for character in string]

                # swap the current index with the step
                string_copy[step], string_copy[i] = string_copy[i], string_copy[step]

                # recurse on the portion of the string that has not been swapped yet (now it's index will begin with step + 1)
                permutations(string_copy, step + 1)
        else:
            raise Exception
    except Exception as error:
        print('Caught this error: string passed in paramater is not a string')

permutations("abc", 0)
```

Why is the exception being raised? Basically I want to prevent someone from passing a random object (that is not a string).

So 123 or Vehicle() would fail.

however I am getting an exception raised on a string (usually the second iteration of my recursive function)

Comment: Try outputting the exception? It contains a stack trace and diagnostic information…

Comment: You are passing a `list` not a `str`... you even have comments that say you are aware of this... although you say "array" (when it is really a `list)`. As an aside, `[character for character in string]` is a verbose way of saying `list(string)`

Comment: Why do you raise an exception and then immediately catch t if you can just print the error message in the `else` branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string_copy` isn't a `str`; it's a *list* of (single-character) `str` objects. Before passing it to `permutations`, you need to join the elements back into a single string.

```
permutations(''.join(string_copy), step + 1)
```